# Function for download file links with php

Tags: php

I want to add some function to download my files that was uploaded some other day. i am not handy with php so i dont know how to add function and generate link for all listed files at time.

here is my php code:-

```
// Destination folder for downloaded files

$date = date('m.d.y'); 
mkdir("uploads/" . $date, 0777, true); 
$upload_folder = 'uploads/' . $date;

// If the browser supports sendAsBinary () can use the array $ _FILES
if(count($_FILES)>0) { 
    if( move_uploaded_file( $_FILES['upload']['tmp_name'] , $upload_folder.'/'.$_FILES['upload']['name'] ) ) {
        echo 'done';
    }
    exit();
} else if(isset($_GET['up'])) {
    // If the browser does not support sendAsBinary ()
    if(isset($_GET['base64'])) {
        $content = base64_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));
    } else {
        $content = file_get_contents('php://input');
    }

    $headers = getallheaders();
    $headers = array_change_key_case($headers, CASE_UPPER);

    if(file_put_contents($upload_folder.'/'.$headers['UP-FILENAME'], $content)) {
        echo 'done';
    }
    exit();
}
```

Comment: You only provided the code that handles the upload, **not** the download.

Think of this: if they were uploaded another time, you first need to make a list of the files that were uploaded. Therefore, you should check out the [`glob`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php)-function.

Comment: How to use this, i don't know about php.

Comment: Have you tried searching for similar scripts? There are a few examples on this site and the internet in general, although they might still need some tweaking for your specific need.
SO is not here to provide for every script you might need.

Comment: Yes i have tried, can you tell me one thing , what should i try here to get path of file

Comment: That's where the `glob`-function comes in. It gets an array of all the filenames matching a certain pattern.